# Can't start PHP localhost

Tags: macos, osx-server, php

So i've done this before but I don't remember the command. I was able to use a directory a localhost file. I've tried `sudo apachectl start` but when I go to `localhost` the page isn't found. I've also tried restarting the server, but the result was still the same. Any ideas? I'm using OSX Mavericks

Comment: What do you mean by "Can't start PHP localhost?" Do you mean that the server starts but you can't use PHP?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with opening `http://localhost` ?

If I'm right you should check your httpd.conf:

Look for: Listen 80 <- This line should not be commented and make sure 80 is written ( when you write localhost into your browser, the browser checks the 80 port on default.
)

If it's 80 then check your if your server root folder is OK:

Must be where the --prefix folder is : normally under /usr/local/apache2.x.x

Then you should check that the DocumentRoot points to the right folder (where your index.html is located if no index.html is present)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the server command you use is running of a different port.

Just typing in `http://localhost` will only work if the port is set to 80.

Try: `sudo php -S localhost:80` to run a PHP server of port 80, the downside of this is that you'll have to run it as root. It's also possible not to run this as root but to configure servers on ports lower than 1240, OS X always needs admin privilege.
The command `php -S localhost:8000` will run without root but you'll have to type in `http://localhost:8000` to get the webbrowser to display your server's contents.